# Tracking the progress of async service activators

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow that invokes certain components in a certain order. At the last stage, 3 components are invoked in parallel by using a `task-executor` on a `publish-subscribe-channel`.

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="pubSubChannel"
    task-executor="executor" />

<int:service-activator id="configure1"
    input-channel="pubSubChannel">
    <bean class="..." />
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator id="configure2"
    input-channel="pubSubChannel">
    <bean class="..." />
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator id="configure3"
    input-channel="pubSubChannel">
    <bean class="..." />
</int:service-activator>
```

I want to figure out when all these components have completed their work to mark some kind of successfully completed status on the item being processed.

What spring integration component or pattern can help me accomplish that?

I want to track that all 3 components completed without errors and also I want to wait until all 3 are done.

Almost like a channel after this flow that receives all 3 messages and be able to track which message came from which activator/channel to know when all 3 messages have been received and the work has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PublishSubscribeChannel` has `applySequence` options, which can be turned on to the `true`.

With that the `PublishSubscribeChannel` sends messages to each subscriber with the `SecuneceDetails` headers.

The `<aggregator>` (as default one) can consult those headers to form a `message group` and produce result exactly after all sequences have came to the `<aggregator>`.

You can find more info on the matter in the Reference Manual.

Comment: Sine `apply-sequence` creates a new message and uses a new `correlation-id`, is there a way to specify or overwrite the correlation-id used by the publish-subscriber channel. I have tried setting the correlated id before this channel but since a new message is generated, it creates a new correlation id as well.

Comment: No, you can't. I can't find (yet) arguments to explain the reason do not have customization on the matter. But would you mind to share the concern why the default algorithm based on the incoming message `id` isn't sufficient for you?

Comment: Let me understand this - So if I have 2 messages coming into the publish-subscribe channel, it sounds like two unique correlation ids will be generated so my aggregator should be able to identify the two groups  (possibly from 6 messages) and release them when the sequence number for each group matches the sequence size. If that the case, then I think I am ok.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. The publish-subscribe-channel uses the incoming message's I'd as a correlationKey for outgoing messages. And aggregator will know which group to build for that. In the end you will have an association between one request message and the reply group for it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Does this seem like a valid release strategy expression for this `release-strategy-expression="[0].headers.sequenceNumber == [0].headers.sequenceSize"`. I got this from the reference manual but I am not sure why [0] (the first message in the collection) and secondly it's not actually working. The aggregator is not releasing messages with this expression

Comment: No reason to worry about the `release-strategy`, if we are based on the default `SequenceDetails` like it is in case of `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Pay attention that the `[0]` sample is especially for the `groupTimeout` feature.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. One last question: the reason I am using aggregator after publisher is to determine that message was received by all its consumers and successfully processed by those consumers. If any of those consumers error out, the message goes to `errorChannel` and, in that case, I will probably need a `group-timeout` to release the queued messages. Is there a default mechanism that can help me determine that messages were released bcoz of group-timeout and not release policy.

Comment: It is there exactly by default. The `sendPartialResultOnExpiry` is `false`, therefore uncompleted group will be discarded. You just should configure `discard-channel` and track those groups from there.